# Pandas get rows by its values from dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a reference dataframe:

ex:

```
  time latitude longtitude pm2.5
  0 .  0        0          0
  1 .  0        5          1

  ......
```

And I have a query with

ex:

```
  time latitude longtitude
  0 .  1        3
  1 .  0        5

  .......
```

I want to get the pm2.5 which matches the rows in query.

I have used the iteration of rows but it seems very slow.

```
predications_phy = []
for index, row in X_test.iterrows():    
    Y = phyDf[(phyDf["time"] == row["time"]) & (phyDf["latitude"] == row["latitude"]) & (phyDf["longtitude"] == row["longtitude"])]
    predications_phy.append(Y)
```

What is the efficient and correct way to get the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given reference dataframe `df1` and query dataframe `df2`, you can perform a left merge to extract your result:

```
res = df2.merge(df1, how='left')

print(res)

#    time  latitude  longtitude  pm2.5
# 0     0         1           3    NaN
# 1     1         0           5    1.0
```

Loops are highly discouraged unless your operation cannot be vectorised.